# When is $\frac1{|x|^p}$ integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B_r(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Given $n\in\mathbb{N},$ for which $p>0$ is the function $\dfrac{1}{|x|^p}$ integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B_r(0)$? I have spent a long time searching for an answer to this question online (and in particular on this site) but cannot find one, which is strange considering how standard it is. I know that for $n=1$ the answer is $p>1$ but don't know what the answer is for $n>1$ or how to go about working it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to the spherical integral, you will find that $p>n$ is the necessary and sufficient condition:

\begin{align*}
\int_{|x|>r}\dfrac{1}{|x|^{p}}dx=\omega_{n-1}\int_{r}^{\infty}\dfrac{r^{n-1}}{r^{p}}dr.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You want
$$  I = \int_r^\infty s^{-p} \mu_{\Bbb{R}^{n-1}}(\partial B_s(0)) \,\mathrm{d}s < \infty  \text{.}  $$

Now the $\Bbb{R}^{n-1}$ measure of the boundary of the $n$-ball of radius $s$ is the [generalized surface area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area) of an $n-1$ sphere embedded in $\Bbb{R}^n$ of radius $s$, $\frac{2 \pi^{n/2} s^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$.  Then
$$  I = \frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)} \int_r^\infty s^{n-p-1} \,\mathrm{d}s  \text{.}  $$
This converges as long as $n -p -1 < -1$, i.e., $n < p$.